# Django Form is_valid() not compatible with python3

Tags: python, django, django-forms, python-3.6

We are using django 2.2.6 and python 3.6.9 in our application.
While using django forms, I am calling this form.is_valid() method and getting this error

**'dict' object has no attribute 'iteritems'.**

Apparently **is_valid()** seems to use **dict.iteritems()** (I understood this from other stackoverflow links) while **iteritems()** has been removed in python3. I somehow have to get it to call dict.items(). Any suggestions on how I can do this? Please do comment if you think my assumption is wrong.

I have this trace

Traceback:

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
34.             response = get_response(request)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
115.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
113.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
21.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/bodhitree/assignments/views.py" in createAssignmentImport
3329.         if form.is_valid():

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in is_valid
185.         return self.is_bound and not self.errors

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in errors
180.             self.full_clean()

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in full_clean
382.         self._clean_form()

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in _clean_form
409.             cleaned_data = self.clean()

Exception Value: 'dict' object has no attribute 'iteritems'

Please help. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Show us the full traceback from the error, so that we can tell where this use of `.iteritems()` is located.

Comment: @jasonharper I have added the traceback sir. I might be wrong about iteritems(), I was assuming that based on the error description. Thank you for the response sir.

Comment: That traceback seems to be missing one or more lines, since it doesn't show any actual call to `.iteritems()`.  The last call it does show is `.clean()`, do you have a method with that name defined in your form class?  Look there, or perhaps in other functions called from that one, for the `iteritems` that you need to change.

Comment: @jasonharper This solved my problem sir. You can post this answer if you wish to sir. I will mark it. Thank you so much. I learnt things.